# XML layout android not aligned perfectly in the center

Tags: android, xml

Here is my xml layout code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/titleset"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Orb Runner"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:textColor="#FF3366CC"/>

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/newgamebut"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="New Game"
    style="@style/Button" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/newgamebut"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="High Score"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    style="@style/Button" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/newgamebut"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="Settings"
    style="@style/Button" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/newgamebut"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Instructions"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    style="@style/Button" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/newgamebut"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="About"
    style="@style/Button" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/newgamebut"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Exit Game"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    style="@style/Button" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What i want to do is to get the instructions textview/button to be completely aligned with the row on top of it currently this is how it looks like.

```
| New Game |   | High Scores |
| Settings |  | Instructions |
|   About  |   |  Exit Game  |
```

I want it to look like this

```
| New Game |   | High Scores |
| Settings |   | Instructions|
|  About   |   |  Exit Game  |
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the width for all TextViews to "wrap_content"?  By telling "Instructions" to fill the parent, it will use as width as it can get.

Comment: yes I have it made no difference =[

Comment: Looks like you'll have to investigate doing this through code.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `android:weightSum` and `android:layout_weight` attributes for the textview/button to assign a relative width.

It might sound weird but I would also recommend using `android:layout_width="0dp"` for your buttons and textviews when using `layout_weight`.